# Click to change inner child and other sections with Javascript/ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

So I made this in Jquery:
[**Game Gallery**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YerPww)

However I need to change it in Vanilla/ES6 and I'm a stuck on how to target the parents child on click and also find the index (`.eq($(this).parent().index()`) for other sections(copy and images section in my case):

My tryout was doing a for loop like:

```
  const mode = document.querySelectorAll('.gamegallery span');
  for (let i = 0; i < mode.length; i++) {
    mode[i].onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
    };
  }
```

But it seems I'm missing something to get the parent to stay in sync with the icons because it sets `.active` but stays `.active` on all icons. I tried:

```
if {
  this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
} 
else {
  this.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
}
```

Which does nothing...theres something else Im missing?

Lastly to also change a different section like the content/images I used:

```
 $('.gamegallery .game-images img').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('active');
    });
```

I basically need to do the same function all at once. Removing **active** to icons - content-images parents. Finding the first object and then go to the parents side and go to each index(which is the first one as default). `node.parentNode.childNodes;` is the one thing I found...I'll keep updating. Not asking to do it but more of what I'm missing from the code I added. Specifically the first part. Coming from a noob EcsMaScript/Modern Vanilla guy.

Comment: Rather than over complicating it with trying to traverse parents and children add the target you want to toggle as a `data-` attribute. When the `span` is clicked remove the active class from all matching spans, add it to the target, and do the same for the text wrapper and image wrapper.

Comment: attributes! nice let me try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than traversing the node hierarchy in search of the elements you want to toggle you can simplify it by specifying a target. This comes in handy if your clicked node's index doesn't match your intended target.

[Checkout this Fiddle for a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kj7khf4c/8/)

You can use the `data-` HTML attribute. For example: `data-target=".xbox"` could be applied to your `span.circle` element since that is what you're adding your click listener to.

`<span class="circle" data-target=".xbox">`

and add the class inside `data-target` to your, well, target:

`<div class="swiper-slide xbox"></div>`

and

`<img src=".." class="xbox">`

On click, you can pull your target from the element with: `this.dataset` and specify what you're looking for. In this case it is: `const target = this.dataset.target`.

With the target's selector found from the dataset we can find the elements with a selector:

```
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.swipe-slider'+target+', .game-images '+target');
```

Once we have the target we can remove the current `active` class from our target's neighbors. In this case, though, I've simply removed it from all.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide, .game-images img').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
```

Then we add the active class with:

`targets.forEach(target => target.classList.add('active');`

Altogether now:

```
function handleClick(e) {

  const target = this.dataset.target;
  const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide'+target+', .game-images '+target);

  document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide, .game-images img').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));

  targets.forEach(target => target.classList.add('active'));

}
```

Comment: atrributes is something I just wasn't thinking about thats an excellent idea thank you! `+target+` makes a lot of sense and much cleaner

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.